# Search for multiple string in another string using reg-exp in python with substitution

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a line as given below

```
line =  00000001: 5869379 AB 0 B CCC_NSE hello how GO_A ELLLEIILKEIII8888**
```

I wanted to search if **00000001 and CCC_NSE and GO_A** exits in a line or not. The catch is the number/string **00000001** can vary, meaning wanted to search for multiple patterns.

I tried using below code,

```
if re.search(r'(%s)(.*)CCC_NSE(.*)GO_A(.*)'%(temp[i][3]), lines, re.M|re.I|re.U) #temp[i][3] just array with multiple number/string.
```

But the error's out as syntax error. Can anyone let me know if the above expression used to find if multiple strings exist in a line is correct or not ?

Example Code Given Below:

```
linez = "00004944 helo how are APPLE helloo.log.gz you MANGO_REQUEST life is cool and as usual SeaPort"
print linez

blue = "00004944"
print blue

if re.search(r"%d(.*)how(.*)you(.*)"%blue, linez, re.M|re.I|re.U)
    print "Exists!"
else:
    print "Nope"
```

Thanks !

Comment: this might be a dumb comment, but your line doesn't end in :, so that is a syntax error in Python.

(i.e. `if ( <stuff> ):`

that's the only syntax error.

Comment: For some reason I can't edit my comment again, but the only problem is the missing :.  Otherwise it seems to work, at least for a single line - well, before you edited the %s to %d.  Put it back to %s.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
if len(re.findall(r'0+1|CCC_NSE|GO_A',line)) >= 3:
    print "ok"
else:
    print "wrong"
```

Comment: The OP said the first number can be anything.